# Autostart a Virtual Machine

Tags: vmware

I've recently installed VMWare Workstation 10.0.3 and decided I'd much prefer to remote desktop to my virtual machine rather than using VMWare's interface.

I therefore marked my Virtual Machine as a shared instance and set it in the `Manaage AutoStart VM's` list, however when I've tried to use it for the first time after a restart I discovered my VM is in a `Powered off` state.

Has anyone else experienced this before? It seems too simple a process to get wrong. Here's a screenshot of my configuration:

[image]